# Python Flask Parameter is rounded up in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, parameter-passing

Python code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def test():
    id = "2138291837273817238" # Can Be some random number
    return render_template("first.html", id=id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 8000)
```

Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Testing</title>
<body style="background-color:#222736;">
<h1 style="color:#f6f6f6">Testing</h1>
</body>

<script>
console.log({{ id }})
</script>
</html>
```

Javascript console:

> 2138291837273817300

As you can see, `2138291837273817238` and `2138291837273817300` are not the same number. The parameter is always rounded up at the 17th number.
Is this just a JavaScript error?
Am I doing something wrong?
And can someone reproduce this?

Comment: `console.log(2138291837273817238); console.log('2138291837273817238')`

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I had to put {{ id }} into "´s,
so its "{{ id }}", then it isnt rounded up!

Comment: Then it is no longer a number. You "number" is larger than the largest JS can handle safely without BigInt (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER: 9007199254740991)